# How to pass parameters into a script in a VS Code webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm running a React app in a VS Code [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) and I'm using Webpack to generate the bundled webview code into a file called `dist/webviews/myWebview.js`.

Here's how my webview code is structured:

I've defined an `index.js` file which contains the root `App` React component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I also have an `index.html` file which pulls in the `index.js` file (note that I replace `{{mainScriptUri}}` with `dist/webviews/myWebview.js` before I set the webview panel content):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src vscode-resource: http: https:; img-src vscode-resource: data: https:; style-src blob: 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'nonce-{{nonce}}'; font-src data: https://unpkg.com;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Webview</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script nonce="{{nonce}}" src="{{mainScriptUri}}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

To open the webview, I've set up a new command (available from the editor context menu) and open the webview using `vscode.commands.executeCommand`.

I have some variables (`myFirstProp = "first string"` and `mySecondProp = "second string"`) in my extension code that are available when I create the webview `vscode.window.createWebviewPanel`.

What I need to do is pass in those two variables `myFirstProp` and `mySecondProp` as `props` to the `<App />` React component in `index.js`. For example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    myFirstProp="first string"
    mySecondProp="second string"
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have tried putting placeholder content in `index.js` similar to what I have done with `index.html` (e.g., `myFirstProp="{{myFirstProp}}"`) and then replace the placeholder with the actual variable value when I set the webview panel content. However, the bundled file `dist/webviews/myWebview.js` is very large and reading/writing to the file is very intensive. I want to avoid this. Is there some way I can do this programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple: insert JS code into your index.html while creating the HTML content for your webview. Introduce another macro name like your `{{mainScriptUri}}` (for example `<script nonce="{{nonce}}">{{init}}</script>`) and replace that during HTML creation with your variables.

Comment: Do you mean insert `<script nonce="{{nonce}}">{{init}}</script>` into `index.html`?

Then when I set the HTML webview content, add something like this: `content = content.replace('{{init}}', 'const myFirstProp = \"first string\"; const mySecondProp = \"second string\";');`?

Then in my `index.js`, reference those global variables like this: `<App myFirstProp={myFirstProp} mySecondProp={mySecondProp} />`?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I meant. I corrected my answer which previously said: insert into index.js.

Comment: what are those double curly brackets. {{ }}.
In my code I got it working with `<script nonce="${nonce}">` . Do you use a templater or is there something I miss?

Comment: I just followed the question and its general syntax. Yes, those double brace are probably for search and replace. I use normal string interpolation instead, just like you.